# Nesting StackNavigator inside a component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm using react-navigation in my application dev (first time..). My porpose is to nest the main and unique StackNavigator inside the component written in the index.js, so I can writing drawer and statusbar code only once and the navigation works only in the free space. I've tried this guide but I don't understand how to apply that paragraph...

The Home component has the specific content of the page.
This my index code interested:

```
export default class BluetoothController extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    header: null,
  };

   render() {
       [...]
       return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={() => drawerView}
        ref={'DRAWER_REF'} // riferimento per recuperare tramite this.refs['DRAWER_REF'] la sidebar
      >
        {/*Il contenuto della view va ALL'INTERNO DEL DRAWER TAG*/}
        <View style={mainStyles.container}>
          <StatusBar
            backgroundColor="#1976D2"
            barStyle="light-content"
          />
          <ToolbarAndroid
            title='Bluetooth Controller'
            titleColor='white'
            style={mainStyles.toolbar}
            navIcon={require('./images/menu.png')}
            onIconClicked={() => {
              // apro la sidebar grazie al riferimento che mi sono creato
              this.refs['DRAWER_REF'].openDrawer();
            }}
            actions={[{ title: 'Info', icon: require('./images/info.png'), show: 'always' }]}
            onActionSelected={(position) => {
              Alert.alert("Instructions", "Welcome to React Native! To get started, edit index.android.js, double tap R on your keyboard to reload, shake or press menu button for dev menu");
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <RouterOutlet/>
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>

    );
  }
}
// impostazione del routing
const RouterOutlet = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  OneBtnMode: { screen: OneBtnMode },
});
BluetoothController.router = RouterOutlet.router;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('BluetoothController', () => RouterOutlet);
```

Now it's showing only the Home content...